# Configure kit for Qt automatically

Tags: c++, qt, gcc, g++, qt-creator

SO!

Let's say I have a number of settings (GCC compiler 9.3.0 built from source, as the distribution I have to use has a very old one, along with environment setup) for a new Kit in QtCreator.

I have managed to setup an environment for compilation and execution of compiled binaries, and made a script to make it work (*like qmake -nocache -recursive/make/sudo make install*, direct execution of g++, and other stuff).

One thing that script can't do at the moment, is that it cannot create a kit for QtCreator with new compilers and environment being set as required, so after running a script, its user has to go through setting it up himself through GUI, which is bad, because this can cause misconfiguration.

This thing I'm trying to create is going to be used by around ~200 people in my company, so leaving readme.txt with instructions just doesn't go well enough for me - I don't want running around fixing missing "{" and "}" in Environment description in created Kits, and other stuff.

Are there ways to create Kits for QtCreator automatically from command line? Maybe, there's some files to edit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've looked into this one a few years back (I wanted to do something similar for registering Buildroot toolchains automatically in QtCreator), and I was unable to find an off the shelf solution. So i think there are 2 ways to implement this:

a) Implementing a command line utility the manipulate the ~/.config/QtProject/qtcreator/{toolchains,profiles}.xml files. Maybe by (re)using the existing C++ implementation within QtCreator, or just re-implement it ie. in Python. Back than I didn't start to work on this as there was no real business need.

b) Switching to qbs, as qbs has support for setting up toolchains from the command line ( see: https://doc.qt.io/qbs/cli-setup-toolchains.html)

If you decide to go with solution a), please let me know and maybe we can partner up to implement it.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I think i'll look into a complexity of changing these files by myself, and compare the time cost of it with me running around colleagues for a week or so =D

If I'll decide to actually implement it, I think, i'll post it here, so stay tuned if you're interested =3

Answer (score 1):

Check out the command line [sdktool](https://github.com/qt-creator/qt-creator/tree/master/src/tools/sdktool) bundled with QtCreator:

> The SDK tool can be used to set up Qt versions, tool chains, devices
> and kits in Qt Creator.
>
> There still is a lot of knowledge about Qt Creator internals required
> to use this tool!

I haven't tried it yet, but I did find the executable under `Tools/QtCreator/libexec/qtcreator` subdirectory of the Qt Creator installation directory. `./sdktool --help` works for me under Linux.